# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'pos' of undefined" after deleting data from chart

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I'm trying to clear data from the all charts (Highcharts) in my Angular application. After all i am getting an error as in the subject. I do not understand how to fix it.

```
public clearChart() {
    while(this.chart.series.length > 0) {
        this.chart.series[0].remove(true);
    }

    while(this.chart.yAxis.length > 0) {
        this.chart.yAxis[0].remove(true)
    }
}
```

This code works fine, after clicking in the button the charts are cleared and i can generate them again if i want ( but i am getting the error after clearing). This is not looking nice, and i do not want to hide an error with try catch (bad idea). Any idea what can i do with it? Maybe the method is not the best for clearing data in the charts, does it?

Comment: Show stack trace of the error and the part of code near the line where it happend.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the array you want to delete equal to [ ].
In your case:

```
this.chart.series[0] = [];
this.chart.yAxis[0] = [];
```

Comment: this makes sense, and work inside application, but the chart is not going to redraw(). I tried to redraw() but it does not to that. i will check what i can do with this.

Comment: Your case is not very clear because you don't provide enough details about your problem...if you want try to be more accurate in order to help you. You can also try to use .filter(item => false). Maybe this will redraw your chart.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution in my case. Firstly i made a mistake, because charts are genereted by store and i should not clear it without the Store. The solution was simply.

I have created an action in the reducer which push the chart state to the initial state. The action is charging after clicking the button, so the chart is rendered to the initial state.

This is easier way if someone using Ngrx. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for a help :)